# Run app from last Activity after app kill

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my app I have 3 activities:

1 activity:
It is starting Activity

In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".First">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

2 activity:
It is login screen Activity.

3 activity:
Activity is showing after correct Login.

In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Third">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In 3. Activity I have button logout. When I click logout button. App is going to Activity 2. And after restart (kill app and start again). App started from 1. Activity. And it's correct.

But when I don't click logout button and restart(kill app and start again). App must started from 3 Activity (user must be still logged-in).

Probably I should manipulate intent flag.

Comment: Do you have a flag that indicates it has been logged-in ? And do you check for it in activity 3

Comment: Nope, I'm only validate Login and Password. If correct -> startActivity

Comment: Okay, just one more question who exactly kills your app ?? the system or you ??

Comment: In fact both of you can't kill the app simultaneously, so if you are the one who kill the app by swiping it from recent tasks. Android will always start the launcher activity.
 @Evin1_ suggests a good way to add a flag on login and check it upon activity startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a key-value pair in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) **AFTER** you log in successfully with the Activity 2.

Then in your Activity 1 check if the key-value pair exists, if it does then go to Activity 3, if not then go to Activity 2.

Example:

**Activity2.java** (After a succesful login)

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("user_logged_in", "true");
editor.apply();
```

**Activity1.java** (When starting)

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String isLogged = sharedpreferences.getString("user_logged_in", "not_logged"
if (isLogged.equals("true"))){
  //User logged in. Go to Activity 3
}else{
  //User NOT logged in. Go to Activity 2
}
```

Also, make sure you clear the key from the SharedPreferences when logging out.

Here is a tutorial, it might help:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm

Comment: Can you tell me what is prefs in prefs.getString("user_logged_in", "true")?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that should return a String (the value that is inside the SharedPreferences with the key "user_logged_in"), let me modify my answer.

Comment: The second parameter of the getStirng method is their default value i.e. if it doesn't find the value it will return "not_logged".

Comment: Thanks for your help. After small modification:
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String isLogged = sharedpreferences.getString("user_logged_in", "not_logged");

It works. Thanks

Comment: @Bartosz you must read about the life cycle of android activities and components. It will help you so much.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html